# How to load multiple models in flutter?

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite

I want to get a keypoint from Posenet and then put that keypoint value back into my custom model.

Can I do this by loading two models from Flutter at the same time?

Comment: I was wondering if you have found the solution for this since it had been nearly a year. Thanks!